# UILocalNotification wrong fire date

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have an alarm that I would like to run Mon, Sat & Sun. Pretty simple stuff. I use this code to create a UILocalNotification. Since today is Sat I am testing it to see if alarm goes off today.

```
//User picks a time from a date picker that shows only hours and mins
NSDate *selectedDate = [datePicker date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *selecDateComp = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:selectedDate];

NSInteger hour = [selecDateComp hour];
NSInteger minute = [selecDateComp minute];

//NSLog(@"hour: %d ... minute: %d ...", hour, minute);


// set components for fire time
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit  fromDate:now];


[componentsForFireDate setHour:hour];
[componentsForFireDate setMinute:minute] ;

//testing
[componentsForFireDate setWeekday:2]; //mon
[componentsForFireDate setWeekday:1]; //sun
[componentsForFireDate setWeekday:7]; //sat

NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForFireDate];

NSLog(@"componentsForFireDate: %@ ... fireDateOfNotification: %@", componentsForFireDate, fireDateOfNotification);

    //I use this fireDateOfNotification date in my UILocalNotification
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;

    notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification ;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ;
    notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Wake Up Time!"] ;
    notification.userInfo= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:titleStr forKey:titleStr];

    notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

    NSMutableString *notifSoundStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ small.mp3", alarmSound];
    notification.soundName=notifSoundStr;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification] ;
```

Here's the problem, if you look at my firedate its last week. Because of this no notification is run today even though today is Sat.

```
componentsForFireDate: <NSDateComponents: 0xc0f9080>
Calendar Year: 2014
Month: 5
Leap month: no
Hour: 11
Minute: 16
Week (obsolete): 22
Weekday: 8 ... fireDateOfNotification: 2014-05-25 15:16:00 +0000
```

Now here's the crazy part, if I remove Sun from the notification and only do Sat & Mon, the fire time works and a notification happens today. What's happening here? I am lost

```
...
[componentsForFireDate setWeekday:2]; //mon
[componentsForFireDate setWeekday:7]; //sat

componentsForFireDate: <NSDateComponents: 0xf8af890>
Calendar Year: 2014
Month: 5
Leap month: no
Hour: 11
Minute: 19
Week (obsolete): 22
Weekday: 7 ... fireDateOfNotification: 2014-05-31 15:19:00 +0000
```

Comment: if you'd use correct indention, it might be easier to read your code.

Comment: still not 100% but better.

Comment: I doubt that one date component can have several weekdays set at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things you are doing this:

```
[componentsForFireDate setWeekday:2]; //mon
[componentsForFireDate setWeekday:1]; //sun
[componentsForFireDate setWeekday:7]; //sat
```

This is not doing what you think it's doing. You are not setting 3 weekdays you are setting a single value and then changing it twice. The last thing you set is the value that gets used.

To set the alarm for 3 different days you will need to create 3 different notifications.

To be honest the fact that the data is in the past has no bearing on the problem because you have set it up as `notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;` therefore it will just ignore the first date and schedule for the next week.

For example if I log out the dateComponents I get

```
<NSDateComponents: 0x8d89c80>
    Calendar Year: 2014
    Month: 5
    Leap month: no
    Hour: 16
    Minute: 41
    Week (obsolete): 22
    Weekday: 7
```

but if I print the local notification it actually shows the correct date - a week on

```
<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x8f49580>{fire date = Saturday, May 31, 2014 at 4:41:00 PM British Summer Time, time zone = Europe/London (GMT+1) offset 3600 (Daylight), repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Saturday, June 7, 2014 at 4:41:00 PM British Summer Time, user info = (null)}
```

---

The format that you are using for the components is deprecated `NS<Interval>CalendarUnit` and you should instead use `NSCalendarUnit<Interval>` which is better form as it's just the last part of the identifier that changes. This allows you get autocomplete to do most the work as you type

Comment: thanks. I need to go back to my drawing board and create 3 local notifications for a future dates that repeats. You recommend to use NSCalendarUnitWeekday?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are misusing `weekday`. It applies to the current week. The way to do what you are asking to do is to figure out how many days from now to fire and add that to the current day's day component.

Another problem is that you are trying to make three local notifications out of one. You can't. This is not a complex repeating alarm. It is a single notification with a single date-time, boom. If you want three notifications, make three notifications.